# How can I replace the first three hyphens in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Change

12-16-23-some-words-now

to

12/16/23/some-words-now

thanks!! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the characters between the first three dashes are always numbers, you can do it like this:

```
variable = variable.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-/, "$1/$2/$3/");
```

If they could be any arbitrary characters, then you can do it like this:

```
variable = variable.replace(/^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-/, "$1/$2/$3/");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YySFh/

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
'12-16-23-some-words-now'.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-/g, '$1/$2/$3/');
```

Are the first three always numbers?

Comment: Ah, @jfriend00 edited his answer just as I was answering. His won't necessarily replace the first three though, as he is missing the `^` operator.

Comment: yep. I'm generating these strings for one purpose where they cannot have backslashes, then use them to direct to a page, which requires the date (first three numbers) to be within backslashes.

Comment: +1 for noticing that it's actually three dashes that should be replaced, -1 for not noticing that there is no digit following the third dash :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = foo.replace(/^(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*)$/, "$1/$2/$3/$4");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZv9e/).

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*)
```

Replace:

```
$1/$2/$3/$4
```

Comment: This one gets my vote. (`[^-]*` is more precise and faster than `.*?`). Say what you mean - mean what you say! +1

Answer (score 0):

This exact structure can be fixed like this:

```
var string = "12-16-23-some-words-now";
var hyphensFormatted = string.substr(0, 9).replace(/-/g, "/");
var formattedString = hyphensFormatted + string.substr(9, string.length);
console.log(formattedString);
```